# monolog: логирование кириллицы

Tags: php, логирование

`Monolog` на сервере некорректно отображает кириллицу.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('logs/app.log', Logger::DEBUG));
$log->addInfo('Результат', array('тест' => 'тест'));
```

На локальном компьютере:

`app.log`:

```
[2016-07-14 17:00:28] test.INFO: Результат {"тест":"тест"} []
```

На сервере

`app.log`:

```
[2016-07-14 17:01:24] test.INFO: Результат {"\u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442":"\u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442"} []
```

Comment: на сервере, вероятно, версия PHP < 5.4

Comment: Да,на сервере 5.3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опция [`JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`](http://php.net/manual/ru/json.constants.php), позволяющая `json_encode()` записывать unicode-символы в исходном виде без трансформации в `\u0442`, появилась в PHP начиная с версии 5.4.0, поэтому на сервере её нет, и unicode символы записываются в escaped-виде.